# search a stringlist for a value , avoid this loop, short code version

Tags: delphi

Can I do this better:  search a stringlist for a certain value ???

```
function searchstringlist (MyStringList : TStringList; MyValue : String) : Boolean;
var   i : Integer; 
begin
     result := false; // added to prevent compiler warning
     for i:= 0 to  MyStringList.Count-1 do
       begin

       if pos ( MyValue, MyStringList[i] ) > 0 then 
              begin
               result := true;
               exit;
              end;
       end;
end;
```

Comment: The compiler should warn you that result may be undefined

Comment: Or are you looking for [`TStrings.IndexOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TStrings.IndexOf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the value is inside the `TStrings.Text`.

And you should use the abstract `TStrings` and string parameters should be `const`.

And you should name the function properly to let others know, what you are doing inside

```
function ContainsStr(const AStrings : TStrings; const ASearchStr : String) : Boolean;
var
  LIdx : Integer;
begin
  Result := Pos( ASearchStr, AStrings.Text ) > 0;
  if Result then
  begin
    for LIdx := 0 to AStrings.Count - 1 do
      if Pos( ASearchStr, AStrings[LIdx] ) > 0 then
        Exit;
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Your (and of course my) function works like this

```
var
  LStrings : TStrings;
begin
  LStrings := TStringList.Create;

  LStrings.Add( 'foo' );
  LStrings.Add( 'bar' );

  ContainsStr( LStrings, 'foo' ); // True
  ContainsStr( LStrings, 'bar' ); // True
  ContainsStr( LStrings, 'foo'#13#10'bar' ); // FALSE

  // but also

  ContainsStr( LStrings, 'oo' ); // True
  ContainsStr( LStrings, 'o' ); // True
  ContainsStr( LStrings, 'ar' ); // True
```

If you only want to find the `'foo'` and `'bar'` you only have to do

```
function ContainsStr( const AStrings : TStrings; const ASearchStr : string ) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := AStrings.IndexOf( ASearchStr ) >= 0;
end;
```

Comment: Why include the loop?

Comment: Without the loop this only works reliably if the search string does not contain line breaks. I don't see why the loop alone is not a good solution though.

Comment: @jpfollenius that is not correct, a single row of a `TStringList` can contain a line break ;o)

Comment: Yes but the `TStrings.Text` approach will give false positives. For example a search for 'a' + sLineBreak + 'b' will return true in a string list with items 'a' and 'b'. This is why you need the loop in the positive case (I answered to David's comment).

Comment: @jpfollenius yes **that** is the case for that loop

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want the function behave exactly like the original function - but I am not sure if that is really what OP is looking for :o)

Comment: That makes the Pos pointless. Makes the code slower and adds heap overhead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It should be faster if the search string is not found inside the list, but is indeed slower if it is inside. But I guess OP is looking for the `TStrings.IndexOf` :o)

Comment: @SirRufo I'm not so sure. Reading the `Text` property is expensive.